# Can I learn multiple fighting styles?

Tags: dnd-5e, multi-classing, ranger, fighter, fighting-style

I just got a level in Fighter and I want to pick the archery fighting style.
I'm already a level 4 Ranger with the dueling fighting style.

Can I have two different fighting styles at once even though it says you can't gain this feature again (unless a level 10 Champion Fighter who can gain a second fighting style).

I checked under the multi-classing features to see if it said anything about having different kinds of fighting styles but it said nothing.

Is it possible to have 2 or 3 different fighting styles without being a level 10 fighter with the Champion archetype, or is that the only way?

Comment: where does it say that you can't gain that feature again? I can't find it in the multiclassing chapter, and the feature itself only states that you can't take the same fighting style (e.g. *Dueling*) twice.

Comment: I am going to vote to close this as a dupe, because I think that NautArch is correct.  If it can be shown that I was in error, please comment or pass advice to me in RPG.SE chat. (A dupe isn't necessarily bad, as we can often ask the same question differently and not realize that how we phrased it didn't match a previous question ...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### You can have several different fighting styles

The only limitation is that you can't pick the same style more than once (emphasis mine):

> You can't take a Fighting Style **option** more than once, even if you later
>   get to choose again. (SRD, p. 24; Basic Rules, p. 27)

This means that you can have the Fighting Style feature itself more than once but you can't choose the same option more than once.

If you already picked the Dueling style as a Ranger, when you get the Fighting Style from fighter you need to pick something else (archery is fine) and you get to have both styles.